# Fourier and inverse Fourier transformation of creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, second-quantization

I've seen two versions of the Fourier transform for the creation and annihilation operators in 2nd quantization, where the annihilation operator of the Bloch/Wannier state is treated as the F.T./I.F.T. of the Wannier/Bloch annihilation operator.

$\displaystyle
a_{i\sigma}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_i}} \sum_{k}^{B.Z.} e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf R_i} a_{\mathbf k\sigma}.
\quad $ (*Fundamentals of Many-body physics*, W. Nolting)

$\displaystyle
a_{i\sigma}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_i}} \sum_{k}^{B.Z.} e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf R_i} a_{\mathbf k\sigma}.
\quad
$
(*Phys540 lecture notes*, K. Sun [Notes](https://sites.lsa.umich.edu/kai-sun/teaching/phys-540/))

How to understand the F.T. relations of annihilation/creation operators?

Comment: Seems like authors are using different conventions to me...

Comment: This is a matter of convention. It amounts to an invertion of the B.Z. $\mathbf{k} \rightarrow -\mathbf{k}$